# The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I am receiving the following error, even though I have set the table view footer before adding the button and applying the constraints. I have tried calling the below method after setting and footer view in `-viewDidLoad` and also in `-viewDidAppear`. I cannot seem to isolate the problem.

> The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint:
>     When added to a
>   view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the
>   view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved
>   before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView
>   _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
>
> 2015-08-12 15:43:05.086 myApp[2293:299005] View hierarchy unprepared
>   for constraint.   Constraint:   Container hierarchy:  >    |
>   >  View not found in container hierarchy:
>   >  That view's superview: ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {800, 75}>

Here is the code that I am using to add the button and apply the constraints:

```
- (void)addButtonContraints{
//Create button
    _nextQuestionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [_nextQuestionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextQuestion) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //_nextQuestionButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200,40);
    [_nextQuestionButton setTitle:@"Next Question" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_nextQuestionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _nextQuestionButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _nextQuestionButton.titleLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Next Question"
                                                                                    attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0f]}];

    //Add shadow to button
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_nextQuestionButton.bounds];
    _nextQuestionButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    _nextQuestionButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _nextQuestionButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
    _nextQuestionButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25f;
    _nextQuestionButton.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;

    [_nextQuestionButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];


    [self.quizTableView.tableFooterView addSubview:_nextQuestionButton];



    //Add contraints to button

    NSDictionary *dict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_nextQuestionButton);

    //width
    [_nextQuestionButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[_nextQuestionButton(200)]"
                                                                                options:0x00
                                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                                  views:dict]];
    //height
    [_nextQuestionButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_nextQuestionButton(40)]"
                                                                                options:0x00
                                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                                  views:dict]];
    //right
    [_nextQuestionButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[_nextQuestionButton]-40-|"
                                                                                options:0x00
                                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                                  views:dict]];
    //top
    [_nextQuestionButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[_nextQuestionButton]"
                                                                                options:0x00
                                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                                  views:dict]];
    _nextQuestionButton.hidden = YES;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the last two constraints to your self.quizTableView.tableFooterView, and not to _nextQuestionButton.